# WHERE clause in SQL Server View not filtering results

Tags: sql-server, view, where-clause

I have a complex view that I am trying to add filters or exclusions on using a `WHERE` clause. View code:

```
SELECT
---OMITTED COMPLEX LOGIC

WHERE
--EXCLUSIONS BEGIN HERE

--records with DATES = "10/01/XXXX" and TIMES = NULL excluded
DATES not like '%10/01/%' or times is not NULL
```

I am seeing records with DATES like "10/01/1985" and TIMES = `NULL` returned when I simply select the view, which I would have expected the `WHERE` clause in the view above to have removed.

[image: results from above query]

The second part of my question is, once I can figure out what I am doing wrong above, and correctly configure the view to return rows with those that meet the criteria above filtered out, what happens when a `where` clause is added to the `SELECT` statement of the view itself? Does it replace the `WHERE` clause embedded in the view or will it work on the filtered set, subsequent to the embedded `WHERE` clause?

Comment: What is the data type of DATES?

Comment: DATES is an nvarchar(4000)

Comment: Why is it an `nvarchar(4000)`? Also show your entire `WHERE` clause. Something may have gone wrong with your operator precedence that you have omitted to show us

Comment: Also, that leading ampersand is bad news for query speed.  If you know the column is formatted MM/DD/YYYY the query could possibly use an index if you can remove the leading %.

Comment: I tried it that way first, but thought I would test it with the leading ampersand. You're right. I will remove that.

Comment: @MartinSmith, nvarchar(4000) because this is a system that is loaded from a bunch of non-standard sources using SSIS. that is how the system is, less than ideal for sure, but i need to work within the construct at hand. The entire where clause is shown here. What is shown is the only exclusion so far.

Comment: @MartinSmith I tried a different approach using your smart question, "why is it an nvarchar(4000). I converted to a date in my SELECT statement and then changed my where clause and it works. 
SELECT .... FORMAT(CONVERT(date,dbo.IBSP_NwisOut.DATES), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
WHERE  not (MONTH(DATES) = 10 and DAY(DATES) = 1) or times is not NULL

if you post a suggestion to cast my data as a date i will be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there could be issue of `AND` and `OR` in the `WHERE` clause. Please use `AND` and `OR` clauses with proper **parentheses** (to associate it better) to correctly propagate your thinking into code well.

Secondly, filter on the view will act as additional filter to the filtered dataset.

Comment: I think my parentheses are correct. It says "DATES not like '%10/01/%' or times is not NULL" .... which is the same as "not DATES like '%10/01/%' and times is NULL". I have tried both ways.

Comment: @kmehta when I tried the same it works fine, please check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=175dda236355b2abebe11e13e15801e3)

Comment: totally bizarre. your code is exactly as i would expect it to work. i cast the nvarchar to a date and did exclusion using month(dates) and day(dates), and now it works. weird.........